# Undefined ajax post with for cycle and string selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, for-loop, jquery-selectors

It's me the jquery/ajax noob :)

I've come up with this:

```
$(function() {  
  $("#moreAdd").click(function() {  
    var dataString = [];
    var selector = '#repeat0';
    var row;
    for(var i=0;$(selector).length != 0;i++){
        row = [];
        selector = '#repeat' + i;
        row.push($(selector).val());
        selector = '#distance' + i;
        row.push($(selector).val());
        selector = '#style' + i;
        row.push($(selector).val());
        selector = '#change' + i;
        row.push($(selector).val());
        selector = '#time' + i;
        row.push($(selector).val());
        dataString.push(row);

        selector = '#repeat' + (i+1); //to check it's finished the for
    }


    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "/index.php/trainings/showAdd",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {  
            $("div#addModalBody").html(data.html);
        }  
    });
    return false;
  });  
});
```

But I always end up with an empty post. I think the selector thing isn't working properly can i create a string and then select by id using that string?
And if thats not it if someone could give me an idea where I'm getting wrong..

Thanks,
James

Comment: what does showAdd look like?

Comment: you are trying to sent an array without any parameter name

Comment: what is the expected parameter names....

Comment: to be a bit more preciese firebug shows the POST as "undefined"

Comment: so you think i should do something like dataString[i].push(row);?

Comment: There is a good change that the ajax call is being made before the for loop actually finishes. You need to be sure that the ajax call executes only after loop has finished.

Comment: @vishal, that is nonesense. There is **no chance** that the ajax call will fire after the for loop. For loops process in line.

Comment: @Liam I can't understand why the time consumed by nested functions cant' be account for... this one is for you http://jsfiddle.net/5axEz/

Comment: @Vishal, your using a setTimeout. setTimeout **is** a deffered process. It does not run inline. **Unlike** for loops. which do run inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can i create a string and then select by id using that string?

Yes, nothing wrong with doing that. The selector is just a string, which you can build up dynamically if you want.

---

> But I always end up with an empty post

I'm guessing that by this you mean the data sent to `showAdd` is empty. This is because your building your data up wrong.

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> Object (passed to data) must be Key/Value pairs.

Your not doing this, your building up and array of strings (`var dataString = [];`) and dumping this into data (`data: dataString`). An array is not a key value pair. This is a key value pair `{key:value, key:value}` So your array is your values, where's your key?

so if your method expects a parameter `(x)` and you want to send `y`. You should do this:

```
$.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "/index.php/trainings/showAdd",
        data: {x:y},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {  
            $("div#addModalBody").html(data.html);
        }  
    });
```

I don't do PHP so I'm not sure what the server side should look like, *and you've not added the expected parameters that should be sent to your server code.*

Comment: actually I would like dataString to look like this at the end: dataString[0][repeat], datastring[0][distance] .... dataString[199][repeat], dataString[199][distance]

Comment: Thats not valid HTTP. What do you want the HTTP to be? it should be `key=value&key=value&....`etc.

Comment: **Add your server side code and I might be able to help**, at the moment I'm just guessing at what your expecting on the server side.

Comment: I have no server side code at the moment I just wanted to see the correct POST in firebug first. Can't I POST an array of arrays?

Comment: No, you can't. Not directly. HTTP only supports key/value pairs. I'm not sure if PHP will map more complex objects though. It may (MVC does), not my field I'm afraid.

Comment: you haven't actually flagged this as PHP. Maybe you need to think about what PHP will accept in a HTTP request first?

Comment: PHP is not a problem, I'm lacking the jquery/ajax side of stuff :) ok I'll think of a better way of doing it with just key:value stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `class` if in this case like,

```
<input type="text" id="repeat0" class="repeat" />
<input type="text" id="repeat1" class="repeat" />
<!-- apply class on elements for distance,style,change,time,etc.-->
```

Your code would be like,

```
var dataString = [];
$('.repeat').each(function(index,value){
    obj={};
    obj['repeat']=$(this).val();// repeat value
    obj['distance']= $('.distance:eq('+index+')').val();// let distance class for all distance values
    obj['style']= $('.style:eq('+index+')').val();// let distance class for all distance values
    obj['change']= $('.change:eq('+index+')').val();// let style class for all distance values
    obj['time']= $('.time:eq('+index+')').val();// let time class for all distance values
    dataString.push(obj);    // add data to final array
});
// your ajax code here
```